# Date Field Calculated Value last Day of last Month

Tags: date, sharepoint, calculated-field

I want to display always the last day of the previous month.

So for example, right now it should display: 28.2.2021

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this formula in calculated column:

```
=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),0)
```

[image]